# Load XML file and load content

Tags: php, html, xml

Hi I am trying to load content from an XML file called articles.xml:
It has  and  as the elements.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecentArticles>
  <Article author="The Reddest">
    <Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>
    <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Link></Link>
  </Article>
  <Article author="The Hairiest">
    <Title>Cake PHP 4 - Saving and Validating Data</Title>
    <Date>1/12/2009</Date>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Link></Link>
  </Article>
  <Article author="The Tallest">
    <Title>Silverlight 2 - Using initParams</Title>
    <Date>1/6/2009</Date>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Link></Link>
  </Article>
  <Article author="The Fattest">
    <Title>Controlling iTunes with AutoHotkey</Title>
    <Date>12/12/2008</Date>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Link></Link>
  </Article>
</RecentArticles>
```

This is the following PHP code I am using to print the elements into the table:

```
                    <!--Make table and print each xml element into it-->
                <center>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Link</th>

                        </tr>

                        <?php

                            //Load the xml file int a variable for use in the table below.
                            $xml = simplexml_load_file("articles.xml");

                            echo("<tr>");

                            foreach ($xml->RecentArticles->Article as $entry)
                            {

                                $title = $entry['Title']
                                $date = $entry['Date'];
                                $description = $entry['Description'];
                                $link = $entry['Link'];

                                echo("<td>$title</td>");
                                echo("<td>$date</td>");
                                echo("<td>$description</td>");
                                echo("<td>$link</td>");

                            }

                            echo("</tr>");

                        ?>

                    </table>
                </center>
```

However nothing is printing into the table.. does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed `$xml->RecentArticles->Article`? Is it `NULL`?

Comment: @u_mulder it shouldn't be, the PHP is accessing an attribute rather than a node value.

Comment: Have sorted now thanks.

Comment: I had to use $ml->Article instead of $xml->RecentArticles->Article aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a (non-existent) attribute value rather than the node value for your content.

**Access "Title" attribute value on the "Article" node:**

```
 $title = $entry['Title']
```

**Access "Title" node value:**

```
 $title = $entry->Title
```

**Example XML:**

```
<RecentArticles>
  <Article author="The Reddest" Title="This is what you are accessing with $entry['Title']">
    <Title>This is what you should be accessing with $entry->Title</Title>
    <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <Link></Link>
  </Article>
</RecentArticles>
```

See [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp) for more information on how to access XML elements.

Comment: Great - would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks!